# API for link safe checker

Tags: python, hyperlink

I develop a project (it's my pet project). This project implied the scenarios when a user posts a link in the post or comments sections or somewhere else, and that's why I have a problem - how to check if this link is safe for users. I need a service like "transparencyreport.google.com" or similar, but I need an API (and desirably free API or at least not so expensive).

Of course, I can try to use Python's Requests library and try to parse the result of the query to this Google service, but I'm not sure that it is a good idea. Perhaps, the API of some service of the database of the blacklisted websites and malicious URLs is better. I would appreciate any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77989563/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).